# Numerical Solution Using Excel about optimal consumption of households

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, optimization, consumption

[image: Numerical Solution Using Excel about optimal consumption of households]

> I'm not sure how to solve this problem. I'm given the discount factor, interest rate, probability of high income shock, and various income shock sizes that I need to use to compute optimal consumption. This is confusing because I'm not given "c1" in the example, so I have to guess an answer for it. What should I do? The math should be simple once I figure out c1.

Comment: c1 can be retrieved from the equation since you have all other information (i.e. the only unknown is c1 so once you plug in all the other values given to you you can get the c1 value so that the equality holds). Of course, c1 will be different for each epsilon value

Comment: Thank you, just realized it

Comment: Please consider editing this so that the question is not in the form of an image.